# Как сверстать адаптивную секцию на FlexBox

Tags: flexbox

Не могу понять как сделать такую секцию, что бы ничего не уезжало при масштабировании. Делаю через FlexBox 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: http://codepen.io/semenchenko/pen/KWyago

Comment: Elena, это работает только с svg ?

Comment: svg для скошенных краев изображений, а вообще принцип флекс: `display:flex; flex-flow: row nowrap`

Comment: т.е. это возможно сделать и с jpg форматом?

Comment: да, конечно, возможно

Comment: .row
  display: flex
  flex-flow: row nowrap
Почему когда меняю класс .row на другой (.flex-container) все проподает ?

Comment: потому что тогда нужно прописывать `.flex-container {display: flex flex-flow: row nowrap}`

Comment: Elena, спасибо что отвечаете! Но все равно не получается как надо.
Можете глянуть код, может все дело в разрешении фото они здесь 
https://drive.google.com/drive/photos, код здесь http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NpwpmK

Comment: Не тут ссылку скинул http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NpwpmK

Comment: примерно так http://codepen.io/semenchenko/pen/ZeaKpK?editors=1100 но вообще проще было бы, чтобы без svg вырезать изображения (как размытое сейчас) и просто их наложить друг на друга немного

Answer (score 1):

```css
#pops{display:flex;flex-wrap:wrap}
.sons{width:46%;height:150px;padding:2%}
.sons:nth-child(1){background-color:green}
.sons:nth-child(2){background-color:yellow}
.sons:nth-child(3){background-color:blue}
.sons:nth-child(4){background-color:red}
```

```html
<div id="pops">
  <div class="sons">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A accusantium aspernatur assumenda autem consequatur,
cumque deserunt dolor doloribus facere fugiat fugit itaque nisi nobis non perferendis quidem quos reiciendis rerum.</div>
  <div class="sons">content</div>
  <div class="sons">content</div>
  <div class="sons">content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Kirill, блоками получается, вся проблема картинках png под углом. Как с этим быть ? вставляю через bgi : url